# Get response of USSD in android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to get the response of USSD message in android through code.Can I possible to get response of USSD in android.If yes,then please give example to receive the response.I am trying this link
[enter link description here](http://codepaste.ru/7545/) but I have not got response.